# Wrap a label in a cell, bad width?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to wrap a multi-line label in a static content table tableview, expanding the row as necessary in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Being a static table, I'm able to set `IBOutlets`; my label is `_instructionLabel`.

Simplifying a bit (there are actually multiple rows in the table), it looks like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *labelText = _instructionLabel.text;
    CGFloat labelWidth = _instructionLabel.frame.size.width;
    CGSize constrainToSize = (CGSize){.width = labelWidth, .height = MAXFLOAT};
    CGSize textSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:_instructionLabel.font constrainedToSize:constrainToSize lineBreakMode: _instructionLabel.lineBreakMode];
    return textSize.height + 10;
}
```

(Before we continue: I'm aware `UILabel` probably doesn't draw to its full width. I plan on figuring out how to compensate for that later, but it's not my problem here.)

Here's the problem: `labelWidth` is wrong. Capturing a screenshot of the label at runtime on the iPad iOS 6 simulator (portrait), it's about 438 pixels wide. I'm getting 638. (On iOS 7, I get 728.)

To try to fix this, I've added these lines to `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    [self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This causes a second pass through the table setup. Now, `labelWidth` is much closer: 482. But that's much further off from what I expect.

I've also tried calling the label's `sizeToFit`, but it seems to be relying on the same bad data.

I have verified that the label's size is *eventually* set correctly, by putting this in `viewWillAppear`:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    CGRect frame = _instructionLabel.frame;
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
    // Output: {{20, 0}, {438, 30}}
});
```

How can I make sure the label's width is set correctly *before* the tableview's final call to `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and **before it's drawn**?

Comment: How is `_instructionLabel` set? Is this tableview a "static content" one instead of "dynamic prototypes" in IB?

Comment: Gah. I meant to add that detail. I'll go back and do it, but yes: it's static content.

Comment: In my tests, the label has the same size in `-viewWillAppear:` as it has in the storyboard. Are you changing the text contents of the label before measuring it? Are you using Auto Layout? What might be happening to cause the layout to change from what's in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes to auto layout. Other than that, nothing's changed. But I'm fairly confident I had this same problem in iOS 5. I never figured it out there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you played with adjusting the row heights from within this method?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath) {
```

It's called after some of the inner workings of UITableView that we're not exposed to have run their course and "adjusted" your layouts a bit.

It's generally the right place to make final tweaks to the visual appearance of your cells. The same requirement for timeliness applies here though too, your code should be very snappy at supplying the required info, so make sure you have the data you need on-hand immediately, and always.

Comment: The only way to adjust the row's height is `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, right? So another callback doesn't really help, except that I could possibly detect something's gone wrong and `dispatch_async` a `reloadData`.

Comment: I said "Row heights" when I meant to say "label width", my bad. You are correctly setting the row height, but if you want the label to end up with the desired width, you have to set _label.width in the willDisplayCell method to make it appear as you like.

Comment: Some of the internal workings of UITableView are coming along AFTER your initial configuration and calculating some of the sizes, so you are allowed a final chance in the willDisplayCell method to make things right. It can be somewhat annoying, but often times you end up feeding the same data to multiple methods of the UITableViewDelegate protocol

Comment: The problem is the height depends on the width iOS calculates. I need to adjust the height, not the width. But thanks. :)

Comment: That does sound different than what I was pointing you towards. Are the labels you are populating your table with static enough that you could pre-calculate the heights for all of them and shove the results into a dictionary or an array scoped to the class when the table is first created, then point the heightForRowAtIndexPath method at that info later?

Comment: What I *might* be able to do is calculate the width for the labels in every orientation (L/P), on every OS (6/7), on every device (standard, Retina, iPad). That sounds insane, but unless I miss my math it's only 12 combinations. I'd much rather have this calculation correct, though. :)